# Angular version 17 можно ли и как подключить несколько прероцессоров (LESS, SASS, SCSS и др)

Tags: angular17

Коллеги, при  создании  нового проекта @Angular version 17 командой

> ng new name

Создаешь проект и тут тебе предлагают выбрать какое

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так вот, на данном этапе у меня только выбор один из 4х

А я хочу иметь под рукой все препроцессоры.

Можно ли это реализовать и как?

Потом добавить или во время создания нового проекта?

Благодарю

Comment: а зачем это надо?

Comment: @Grundy, спортивный интерес...

Comment: ты можешь получить конфиг вебпака и добавить любые нужные тебе настройки